# bootstrap tooltip and angularJs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I'm using the [bootstrap-tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)  and angularJs for display tooltip.

I am using the following code for display tooltip :

```
<div class="input-group">
   <input valid-number ng-model="gotoPageInput" ng-class="{notValidPageNumber: gotoPageInput > totalPage || gotoPageInput<1}" ng-keyup="gotoPage($event,(gotoPageInput>=1 && gotoPageInput<=totalPage))" type="text" class="form-control goToPage " style="width: 70px">
   <button rel="tooltip" title="{{gotoPageInput}}" class="btn btn-default goToPage" ng-class="{disabled: gotoPageInput > totalPage || gotoPageInput<1}" ng-click="gotoPage($event,true)" type="button">go</button>
</div>
```

The first time it works properly Like the picture below :

[image]

See what happens when I change the value from 4 to 5 :

[image]

why ? Two tooltip Displays.Browser tooltip is correct but bootstrap tooltip is Wrong.

Comment: works fine, [http://jsfiddle.net/Nicolai8/p9Xa5/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/Nicolai8/p9Xa5/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[angular-ui bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)**'s tooltip instead of using the jquery tootltip that twitter bootstrap is using.

**[See this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1sWSAVZVZANE9yAZYjOk?p=preview)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn btn-default" tooltip="{{text}}">Go</div>
<input type="text" ng-model="text">
```